# Sum of a sum in python with loops

Tags: python, loops, sum

I've been trying to code this all afternoon. Any advice?

There are two lists: Rep is the replicates of sample 1 and sample 2, and OV is the observed values for each replicate. What I need to do is to Sum all the values in OV belonging to sample 1, then square the result and divide it by n, and then all of that for sample 2, and finally sum both values. (It is the first part of a formula called "sum of squares along" for the Analysis of Variance, I can't upload an image of the formula yet. :(

To test my code I've created two simple lists:

```
Rep=[1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2]
OV=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
```

m is the number of samples, and n is the number of replicates per sample.
I've created another list of the sample number.
This is my code try.

```
m=2
n=6
sum=0
ObsSum=0
a=0
b=0
Sam=[1,2]

for i in OV:
    if Rep[a]==Sam[b]:
        sum=sum+OV[a]
        a=a+1
        print(i,a,Sam[b],sum) 
        ObsSum=ObsSum + (((sum)**2)/n)
    else:
        b=b+1
        sum=0
print(ObsSum)
```

This is what I obtain, and there is one value, 7, the first corresponding to the sample 2, that isn't being taken into account.
Any suggestion?

```
1 1 1 1
2 2 1 3
3 3 1 6
4 4 1 10
5 5 1 15
6 6 1 21
8 7 2 7
9 8 2 15
10 9 2 24
11 10 2 34
12 11 2 45
1614.3333333333333
```

I'm new to Python, and this is my best try.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the first value by using the built-in `sum` function:

```
value=sum(n for n in OV if n in Rep)**2/len(OV)
```

You can use `sum` again for the second part:

```
value2=sum(n-value for n in OV)
```

However, are you sure that's what you want?  That's not how you calculate variance.

Comment: Sorry, I might have not explained myself well. This is from Analysis of Variance (One way ANOVA). Variance in the ANOVA is partitioned into total variance, variance due to groups, and variance due to individual differences.
Also, value2 has to go over the same procedure of value..
What I should obtain here is ((1+2+3+4+5+6)^2/6)+((7+8+9+10+11+12)^2/6)=615

Answer (score 0):

the code is taking the value, but when it takes the value 7 the condition Rep[a] == Sam[b] is false then it goes directly to the statement b=b+1 and restart the sum to zero.

Answer (score 0):

Using the built-in Sum() function will do what you are looking for.

it takes two arguments sum(list_of_numbers, starting_value). You can find documentation and example code [here](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/sum):

As for your bug, the reason the sum is less than you expect is actually not because the value of 7 isn't taken into consideration but instead because the last value (12) isn't. The way "for i in OV" works is it runs the code under it once for every object (in this case numbers) inside the list you have given (OV). The way you have your solution programmed at the moment, it uses one of the 12 iterations skipping over the if statement and implementing the else. This skip takes place at the 7th position. You know this is true because if you look at your output, you're printing the i and it skips the 7th.

6 6 1 21

**<--- i = 7 is missing.** Ran else portion of the code instead because the if statement 
                           wasn't satisfied.

8 7 2 7

There is also another way to do this that you may not have come across yet. You can parse lists into new lists using code similar to what I have below. So with the given information of n, you can create two lists of samples which you can sum separately. Play around with it and see what works for you.

```
OV = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
n = 6

# Python starts numbering positions at 0 instead of 1
list_of_sample_1 = OV[0:5]
list_of_sample_2 = OV[6:11]

sum_of_sample_1 = sum(list_of_sample_1)
sum_of_sample_2 = sum(list_of_sample_2)
```

you can make python automatically parse the lists given a value of n like so:

```
OV = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
n = 6

# Python starts numbering positions at 0 instead of 1
list_of_sample_1 = OV[0:n - 1]
list_of_sample_2 = OV[n:11]

sum_of_sample_1 = sum(list_of_sample_1)
sum_of_sample_2 = sum(list_of_sample_2)
```

Just some food for thought. Good luck with your program!

Comment: Thank you! Very useful to make it simpler, I'll definitely take it into account. However, those lists were just examples, the list I have to analyze contain more than 2 samples with 6 iterations each.

Comment: Then I suggest replacing "for i in OV" with "for i in range(len(OV)+m)". This will help your solution have the ability to solve for multiple number of samples without changing your if/else structure. If the replacement looks foreign, read up on range() and len(), you'll see how combining them will give you the extra iterations you need to overcome the skipping due to the else portion. You might need to pull out the len(OV) portion into it's own variable before putting it into the range call, I don't remember if range() can handle len() call.

Answer (score 0):

Too complex? Maybe. But this works for longer lists with many samples.

```
for i in OV:
    if Rep[a]==Sam[b]:
        sum=sum+OV[a]
        a=a+1
    else:
        ObsSum=ObsSum + ((sum)**2)/n
        sum=0
        sum=sum+OV[a]
        a=a+1
        b=b+1
ObsSum=ObsSum + ((sum)**2)/n
print(ObsSum)
```

I did it thanks to you guys! (: